# Concatenating SQL statement strings

Tags: python

Im trying to concatenate a dynamic insert statement ( over 100 inserts ) and instead executing one by one, i want to concatenate all of the statements into only one variable.

Following, a basic exemple:

```
insert_ = " insert into table ( field,zone) values ('a','b'); "
insert_b = " insert into table ( field,zone) values ('c','d'); "
insert_c = " insert into table ( field,zone) values ('e','f'); "

list = []
list.append(insert_)
list.append(insert_b)
list.append(insert_c)
print list
```

Current output:

```
[" insert into table ( field,zone) values ('a','b'); ", " insert into table ( field,zone) values ('c','d'); ", " insert into table ( field,zone) values ('e','f'); "]
```

Desired output:

```
insert into table ( field,zone) values ('a','b'); insert into table ( field,zone) values ('c','d');  insert into table ( field,zone) values ('e','f');
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Why? If you are doing this for the reason I think, there may be a better way...

Comment: Performance , mostly, i noticed that i can do 1000 inserts at same time in less than 5 seconds. By performing one insert on a loop, i loose one second on opening and closing the connection to the database.

Comment: Don't EVER build up your own SQL statements, use either the Python [DB API](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) or an ORM like [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org). Otherwise you're risking attacks like SQL injection.

Comment: Also, your question title is misleading-- there are no dictionaries anywhere in this question.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but im just using it to insert data into my offline dvd collection.

Comment: @Thales: Ok, that somewhat reduces the security concerns. It still would be much *easier* (and cleaner) to just use [pysqlite](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) or [MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html) ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
c = db.cursor()
values_to_insert = [("a","b"),("c","d"),...]
c.execute_many("INSERT INTO table (val1,val2) VALUES (?,?)",values_to_insert  )
```

this is what execute_many is for ...

Answer (score 3):

Simple as `"".join(list)` . Or don't use a list at all and just use string concatenation, as Hemesh said.

Also, please don't name your list "list". It's a reserved keyword in python (I sometimes fall into this trap myself, but it's a really bad idea).

Answer (score 2):

Just concatenate all of them, no need to use a list.

```
insert = insert_ + insert_b + insert_c
```

Comment: and what if instead variables, results are results from a for loop?

Comment: `insert = ""

 for q in li:

      insert += q   `

Comment: Writing code in comment is so hard. :(  But I hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Since `join` and simple addition have been suggested, here's another option for completeness:

```
insert = '%s %s %s' % (insert_a, insert_b, insert_c)
```